# Getting a CSS element to automatically resize to content width, and at the same time be centered

Tags: css, resize, center

I have a CSS element, with a border around it, that could have one or multiple boxes in it, so the width of the entire div changes depending on how many boxes are present inside of it.  However, I want this whole div to be centered on the screen.

Usually, to center things, I just use:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

But, this time, I have to either float the element or make it inline-block so the size of the div will be resized to the content, and if I do that, the margin-left and margin-right auto does not work, it always just stays on the left side of the screen.

Currently I have:

```
#boxContainer {
    display:inline-block;
    clear:both;
    border:thick dotted #060;
    margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
}
```

I also tried with `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block`.

Does anyone know of a good way to both center a div and allow it to be resized to content simultaneously?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Share some code here for example [http://jsfiddle.net/yTW22/2/] .It's much easier to understand than and could have got some help faster. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried keeping it inline-block, and putting it inside a block-level element that’s set to `text-align: center`?

E.g.

#### HTML

```
<div id="boxContainerContainer">
    <div id="boxContainer">
        <div id="box1"></div>
        <div id="box2"></div>
        <div id="box3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#boxContainerContainer {
    background: #fdd;
    text-align: center;
}

#boxContainer {
    display:inline-block;
    border:thick dotted #060;
    margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
    text-align: left;
}

#box1,
#box2,
#box3 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #999;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Seems to work as you describe: http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/pYaKB/

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the tip, this worked perfectly!  Tricky to use the text-align like that...works both in i.e. and chrome.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Anthony: hurrah! Glad we found a solution, especially to a well-phrased question like yours (because then other people with the same problem will find it more easily). If you’d like to accept my answer (by clicking the tick next to it), other people will find it more easily, and I’ll get 15 sweet rep points.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this cannot be achieved through CSS solely I don't think. You could always use JavaScript to center the `div` once you know its width (i.e. after the boxes have been appended) for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var itemWidth = $('#boxContainer').width();
    var availWidth = $(screen).width();
    var difference = availWidth - itemWidth;
    $('#boxContainer').css('margin: 0 ' + Math.round(difference / 2) + 'px');
});
```

Comment: we’ve got a CSS-only solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343778/getting-a-css-element-to-automatically-resize-to-content-width-and-at-the-same-t/5343821#5343821), although I guess with the use of `display: inline-block` there might be issues in earlier versions of IE.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately using `text-align: center` on the parent container will not work in earlier versions of IE. :-(