# How to align a div to the top of its parent but keeping its inline-block behaviour?

Tags: css, html

See: http://jsfiddle.net/b2BpB/1/

Q: How can you make box1 and box3 align to the top of the parent div `boxContainer`?

```
#boxContainerContainer {
  background: #fdd;
  text-align: center;
}

#boxContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: thick dotted #060;
  margin: 0px auto 10px auto;
  text-align: left;
}

#box1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999;
  display: inline-block;
}

#box2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #999;
  display: inline-block;
}

#box3 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #999;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Help much appreciated...

Acknowledgement: This question is forked from an answer previously given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/20578/paul-d-waite  : [Getting a CSS element to automatically resize to content width, and at the same time be centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343778/getting-a-css-element-to-automatically-resize-to-content-width-and-at-the-same-t/5685908#5685908)

Answer (score 416):

Try the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) CSS property.

```
#box1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #999;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* here */
}
```

Apply it to `#box3` too.

Comment: If you want a universal solution, you should apply the `vertical-align: top;` to `#boxContainer div` selector. It applies the style to all `div` elements inside the `boxContainer`.

Answer (score 42):

As others have said, `vertical-align: top` is your friend.

As a bonus here is a forked fiddle with added enhancements that make it work in Internet Explorer 6 and Internet Explorer 7 too ;)

#### Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/bHMXw/)

Answer (score 9):

You can add float: left; for each of the boxes (box1, box2, box3).

http://jsfiddle.net/Wa4ma/

Comment: Like this one better than vertical-align +1

Comment: Why in the world does this work? I like it, but I would also like to understand it.

Answer (score 7):

Use vertical-align:top; for the element you want at the top, as I have demonstrated on your jsfiddle.

http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html

Answer (score -1):

Or you could just add some content to the div and use inline-table

Comment: why add a table when you can use vertical-align?

Comment: @tcoulson I didn't say use a table, I said you can use display: inline-table, which, 3 years ago had better browser support and made it easy to vertical-align.